# Automatic logouts on startup 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, startup, hdmi, logout

Just installed 16.04 two days ago and it is giving me some very annoying problems on start up.

Every time Ubuntu starts, a logout is triggered by closing any window for the first time, either through Alt+F4 or through the 'x' button. Sometimes it happens twice in a row (startup, close window --> logout, login, close window --> logout). Sometimes this happens also at random after having been logged in for awhile and always on closing a window. I use gnome-flashback with the two bars as my desktop, by the way.

Another problem that I have on startup (that I could ask in a separate question if it's too much for a single one) comes from using a laptop+external display and speakers. I have a laptop connected through an HDMI cable to a monitor with integrated speakers. I want audio and video coming exclusively from this monitor, but every time Ubuntu starts, the audio is coming from the laptop and the video is shared between the two screens. I had the same problem with the video in 15.10, but the problem with the audio is new to 16.04.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: First problem is bug/regression in metacity 1:3.18.3-1ubuntu3. You will need to upgrade to 1:3.18.4-0ubuntu0.1 version.

Comment: Thanks. I do have the 1:3.18.3 version, but I don't know how to upgrade it ("apt-get install --only-upgrade metacity" does nothing and I don't know any better). Should I just wait for the proper Ubuntu patch?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If you don't see metacity then try again later. It was moved from proposed to updates only 3 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You can post it as the answer now if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is bug in Metacity 1:3.18.3-1ubuntu3 and should be fixed by upgrading to 1:3.18.4-0ubuntu0.1 version.

Unfortunately I don't have answer for your second problem...